# Slicing 3d numpy array - misunderstanding

Tags: python, numpy

I know for 3d numpy array I can index like:

```
item = x[0,2,1]
```

or

```
item = x[0][2][1]
```

But slicing work strange for me:

```
item = x[:,:,1]
```

is not the same as:

```
item = x[:][:][1]
```

What did I miss?

Comment: read more here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like @ffisegydd's answer, but I wanted to point out that this is not unique to numpy arrays. In python the statement `result = A[i, j]` is equivalent to `result = A[(i, j)]` and the statement `result = A[i][j]` is equivalent to:

```
tmp = A[i]
result = tmp[j]
```

So if I use a dictionary:

```
A = {0 : "value for key 0",
     (0, 1) : "value for key (0, 1)"}
print(A[0][1])
# a
print(A[0, 1])
# value for key (0, 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

`x[:]` will return the full array, without doing any actual slicing. By that logic, so will `x[:][:]`.

As such, `x[:][:][1]` **is equivalent to** `x[1]`. This is why it's not the same as `x[:,:,1]`.

Comment: could you just replace the word "copy" with something else, since it's not really a copy and people often get confused on this issue.

Comment: @tom10 if I do `id(x)` and `id(x[:])` they return different values though. So does that not make it a copy? I'm happy to change it, otherwise. EDIT: never mind I spoke to some wiser people than me, and they suspect it isn't a copy, so I'll edit it now.

Comment: The header is copied (hence the different ids), but it will be the same data in the same memory location.. hence the word "copy" is confusing.